# How can I add multiple columns in a Tableview with Swift?

Tags: swift, tableview, multiple-columns

I'm new with Swift and Xcode and I'm trying to make a table where I can see multiple informations in the same row: Description; Qty; Unit Price; Total Price; Discount. 

First I created an array where I was adding the first column "description". Then then I created a tableview and was able to put this array in the tableview, but seeing only the column "Description". But when I was digging more into Tableviews, I realized that maybe it's not what I actually need.. 

I need a row (/cell?/object) that I can display multiple information within different columns. I need also to be able to add a bottom, like in the example bellow "Discount", where I can do something with that row information. 

Please could you advise what I should do? 

Do I have to create an array of arrays together with some RectObj and manually place each string in the correct location and so on and so on? Or do we have something that can do that for me?

I appreciate the attention and help. 

Marcelo

Comment: [Example](http://www.ipadenclosures.com/php-oak/themes/global/admin_images/apps/ShopKeep-Screen-Shot_01.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you consider using a custom cell in a table. The cell would have labels for each of the columns which you can fill in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView.

However, you may have difficulty filling in all your columns in a row in the portrait mode if this is an iPhone app. It should work on an iPad.